# R: Using bn.fit to get conditional probabilities in each category as output for a Bayesian network

Tags: r, bayesian

I've generated a Bayesian network via the bnlearn package and the bn.fit function that has 6 predictor variables for the one 'eyecolor' variable. I'm trying to get the probabilities of each possible eyecolor category (of which there are 3) for each sample.

```
dag_iris<-empty.graph(nodes=c("rs122","rs128","rs129","rs139","rs180","rs168","eyecolor"))
dag_iris<-set.arc(dag_iris,from="eyecolor", to="rs168")
dag_iris<-set.arc(dag_iris,from="eyecolor", to="rs128")
dag_iris<-set.arc(dag_iris,from="eyecolor", to="rs122")
dag_iris<-set.arc(dag_iris,from="eyecolor", to="rs129")
dag_iris<-set.arc(dag_iris,from="eyecolor", to="rs139")
dag_iris<-set.arc(dag_iris,from="eyecolor", to="rs180")


bn.mle<-bn.fit(dag_iris,data=iris.geno[,2:8],method="mle")
bn.grain<-as.grain(bn.mle)
predict.mle<-predict(bn.grain,"eyecolor",newdata=iris_geno[,2:7],predictors =     
c("rs129","rs180","rs128","rs168","rs139","rs122"),method="bayes-lw")
```

This output gives the highest likely category (either "blue", "brown", or "int") for each sample, but I want the numerical probability values in each of those categories (for blue, brown, AND int).  I've googled and have seen the use of 'prob' in the predict function of the bn.fit utilities, but it gives back the error as an unused argument.  I've looked at the other questions somewhat related to this and have not seen anything that could help with this.  I feel like I'm missing an argument that would solve this, or is there a different function?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: if your BN is not to big, and discrete, you can calculate these exactly using gRain

Comment: So I did it that way also, but when I compared it to the Hugin data I generated (which is why I switched to R because I only have the Lite version and it won't handle my bigger BN) it had inverted some of the data  for the brown and int categories, so I wanted to try another way

Comment: GMD886, do you mean that some of the predicted categories using bnlearn were different from Hugin or gRain was different from Hugin? If the first, you should try increasing n, (the default , I think is 500, try 5000, time permitting) as bnlearn uses sampling methods. If the second, I'd look to see how Hugin is estimating as gRain uses exact methods

Comment: Technically both ways I used the grain() function, but the other way not shown here I had generated CPTables and compiled that list and then used grain() and predicted from that network.

Comment: ps a wee example on the effect of increasing the sample size:..`p1 <- predict(bn.fit(hc(learning.test), learning.test), node="E", data=learning.test, method="bayes-lw") ; p2 <- predict(bn.fit(hc(learning.test), learning.test), node="E", data=learning.test, method="bayes-lw") ; table(p1, p2) ;
p1 <- predict(bn.fit(hc(learning.test), learning.test), node="E", data=learning.test, n=4000, method="bayes-lw") ;  p2 <- predict(bn.fit(hc(learning.test), learning.test), node="E", data=learning.test, n=4000, method="bayes-lw")  ; table(p1, p2)`

Comment: sorry I just notice that you had used the gRain package in your code.. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

By converting the `bnlearn` net to a `gRain` one, I found that simply adding the `type="distribution"` attribute did exactly what I needed:

```
predict.mle <- predict(bn.grain, c("eyecolor"), 
                       predictors=c("rs129","rs180","rs168","rs128","rs139","rs122"), 
                       newdata=iris_test[,2:7] ,
                       type="distribution")
```

Comment: Thank you for that clarification